# C++: How to properly print out the long long int using cout

Tags: c++

I wrote a code to get the factorial of a number in C++.

Here is the code.

```
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 unsigned long long getFactorial(int);

 int main(int argc, char **argv) {
         int num = 5;
         unsigned long long factorial = getFactorial(a);

         cout << "Factorial of " << num << ": " << factorial << endl;

         return 0;
 }

 unsigned long long getFactorial(int num) {
         int i;
         unsigned long long factorial = 1;
         for(i=1; i<=num; i++) {
                 factorial *= i;
         }

         return factorial;
 }
```

When I assign 5 to the `num` value, it properly prints out the right value, 120. But when I assign bigger numbers, for example 100, it simply prints out 0. How can I modify the code to properly print out the result on the console?

Comment: a uint64_t (8 bytes) can hold around 93!.   100! is simply too big.  Try smaller than 92!, and maybe use only unsigned long long, no ints or signed numbers.

Comment: For bigger factorials, look into gmp (extended precision arithmetic).    It can handle 1000!, and generates a big string as result.

Comment: How did you arrive at the conclusion 92! can fit into a 64-bit integer?  It can't.  20! is the limit.

Comment: `fib(93)` is the limit for 64-bit unsigned integers, he probably just confused them

Answer (score 1):

Now I found the answer by myself.

By using the `gmp` library, it became much easier to deal with the big integers.

Here's the modified code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gmpxx.h>

using namespace std;

mpz_class getFactorial(int);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        int num = 100;
        mpz_class factorial = getFactorial(num);

        cout << "Factorial of " << num << ": " << factorial << endl;

        return 0;
}

mpz_class getFactorial(int num) {
        int i;
        mpz_class factorial = 1;
        for(i=1; i<=num; i++) {
                factorial *= i;
        }

        return factorial;
}
```

In order to use the `gmp` library, I included the `<gmpxx.h>` header file. Next I changed the data type of the `factorial` variable and the return type of the `getFactorial()` function from `unsigned long long` to `mpz_class` which is the data type that represents the big integer.

After modifying the code, I compiled with GCC using the following flags.

`$gcc test.cpp -lstdc++ -lgmpxx -lgmp -o test`

The `-lgmpxx` and `-lgmp` flags are required to compile the code using the `gmp` library.

Now it works fine.

Comment: Good thing... you learn by far much when you find the solution by yourself, congratulations!